# How to view error messages in Scrapy recursive scraping?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy for recursive scraping. I wrote my spider so that it could follow the "next page" button and scrape each row in every page. However, my spider only scraped 80% of the rows that I originally expected. I want to view all error messages so that I can know the specific content that my spider failed to scrape. I know that errors are displayed on the Windows cmd as the spider runs, but there are too many lines on the cmd for my naked eyes. In addition, I was only allowed to scroll up to a certain point, which means it's impossible to view all error messages this way. So is there a way to display all error messages? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are command-line arguments you can use to [log the output](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html):

`--logfile FILE`: Overrides LOG_FILE

`--loglevel/-L LEVEL`: Overrides LOG_LEVEL

You can use them along with your spider with:

```
scrapy crawl my_spider --logfile myspider.log
```

And later just look for the errors in the file.